# Why LoggingFilter is not executed?

Tags: java, logging, interface, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using java 8. I'm using jersey 2.26 as jax-rs implementation. Everything works fine, but I'm not being able to log.

I have generated WS stub with eclipse:

File -> new project -> maven prokect -> filtered jersey 2.26 -> inserted my groupid and artifactid -> finish.

The following is my resource class:

```
package mypackage;

import ...

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @EJB
    private Service service;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().toString());

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "application/json" media type.
     *
     * @return MyObject that will be returned as a application/json response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Logged
    public MyObject getIt() {
        logger.info("LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOG");
        //some computation
        return result;
    }

}
```

The following is my LoggingFilter:

```
package log;

import ...


@Logged
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().toString());

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        logger.info("RESPOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONSE");
        logger.info(requestContext.toString());
        logger.info(responseContext.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        logger.info("REQUEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEST");
        logger.info(requestContext.toString());
    }

}
```

The following is my interface:

```
package log;

import ...

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NameBinding
public @interface Logged { }
```

The following is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>mypackage</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

filter methods in LogginFilter are never called. "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOG" is printed, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need. First, with the following

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>mypackage</param-value>
</init-param>
```

You only list `mypackage` as the package to scan but the filter is in the `log` package. You could add the `log` package delimited with a comma.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>mypackage,log</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But generally the way you should package your application is to have at least a root package and all other packages are subpackages. For example

```
com.foo.resources
com.foo.filters
```

Here `com.foo` is the root package. What you can do here is just list `com.foo` as the package to scan and Jersey will recursively scan it, including `com.foo.resources` and `com.foo.filters`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.foo</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Second thing you need is `@Provider` annotation on the filter. The package scanning looks for `@Path` and `@Provider` annotated classes to register.

Answer (score 0):

This site is the Bible: https://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/

You have to choose between:

1. register your jersey providers in web.xml
2. create application extending resourceConfig.

I chose the first possibility.